# How to choose between sound outputs without unplugging hardware?

Tags: linux-mint, audio, devices, pulseaudio, output

I am currently running the following:

```
4.15.0-46-generic GNU/Linux
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Release:    19.1
Codename:   tessa
```

I have my headphones plugged into their dedicated port, however, I also have stereo speakers plugged into the back of my motherboard which I use as well. Currently, to use either of them I have to physically unplug my headphones to use my stereo speakers.

**My question is: can I switch between them in the Operating System itself?**

When I plug my headphones in, the Line-out audio device gets replaced by my headphones. In windows, I was given both options simultaneously, making switching between them a bit less of a hassle.

[image: Headphones as output device]
[image: Line out as output device]

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `paprefs`.

You need to install it:

```
$ sudo apt install paprefs
```

Then, once you run it, go to the Tab "Simultaneous Output" and tick the following box:

[image: Simultaneous Outputs]

A newly output is created that you need to select in the tab "Output" from the PulseAudio preferences, which broadcast the sound on every output:

[image: select new output]

This should do the trick.